# Two SSL certificates for one domain, one for encryption, and other for authentication?

Tags: c#, authentication, ssl, iis

I am building an web app, that will use ssl certificates for authentication. I will be using IIS web server.

The problem is that CA is self-signed and users will get red bar in browser.

So, i was wandering if it is possible to get a proper certificate from global provider, and use that certificate for encryprion in order to get green bar (or at least no red bar).

And then, on top of that, get server certificate from the local CA, for the same domain, but use it only for authentication pusposes, since local CA will provide users a certificate on PKI device.

Is this setup even possible? I am no expert in this area, so I would appreciate any pointers, or maybe I am on a wrong track, and this is not possible to achieve?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A certificate in TLS is **not used for payload encryption** in the first place. A certificate is used for authentication and in case of the obsolete RSA key exchange also for sending the premaster secret from the client to the server by encrypting it with the public key of the server. Apart from being obsolete it is **not possible to use a different certificate** for the RSA key exchange than for the authentication.

Comment: OK, as I said I am no expert in this area, maybe I didn't explain myself very good. 
What I want is one server certificate, that you get from GoDaddy or wherever to secure my web site in a proper way. 
At the same time, I have users which will have their own certificates issued to them by CA which is not trusted online. I expect that they would need to issue server certificate for my web server. So I would have 2 certificates installed on my web server. I am wandering if that scenario is possible?

Comment: @MilosMijatovic: It is not quite clear to me. Do you want "users with their own certificate" to use these certificates as client certificates in a mutual authentication (user authenticates against the server) or do you want to use these certificates as "normal" server certificates. In the latter case: should these certificates are for a different (user specific) domain then or for the same. In the latter case: how should the server know which certificate to provide (it can only be one).

Comment: I want to use both :) In a ideal setting, if CA was trusted online I expect that I would install web sever cert provided by CA that would both encrypt payload, and be used to authenticate clients (i don't know, maybe this is also not possible). But since CA is not trusted, I get red bar, and browsers nag. I was thinking to install another certificate just for encryption. And yes, for the same domain. Your last question is my issue: is there a way to say to web server, use this cert for encryption, and the other one for authentication.

Comment: Actually, as I see it, I just need a way for web server to accept the client certificates, but I think that there needs to be a server certificate based on which will browsers actually send client certificate that I need to authenticate.

Comment: @MilosMijatovic: Client and server certificates are totally independent. Client certificates are checked by the server and server certificates are checked by the client. To check the client certificates at the server you need to configure there  which CA is trusted for issuing client certificates.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. Based on your last reply, do you think I could just install CA root cert on my web server, without use it in bindings for my web site, and it will accept client certificates?

Comment: @MilosMijatovic: see for example [this documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2014/02/12/how-to-configure-iis-client-certificate-mapping-authentication-for-iis7/) on how to setup IIS for mutual authentication.